# How to Connect Device via SPP profiles programmatically in xamarin

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, spp

i have bluetooth device, how can I connect to it programmatically in xamarin (monotouch) via SPP profile, and read device message
I need to programmatically identify the the available devices and choose my device?
i try this code

```
CBCentralManager _manager = new CBCentralManager ();
var spp = Guid.Parse("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
_manager.ScanForPeripherals(new [] { spp });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i also had same problem, and found out that you can't access BlueTooth SPP.

Instead you need to go via the External Accessory API.

this [thread](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/476/corebluetooth-spp-sample) helps me to work in right direction. Hope it may helps you too!